# force to open youtube link in App instead of Safari iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube

Is there anyway to open a youtube link in youtube App instead of Safari for mobile ?

I can't find anything about this, it will be really helpfull !

Thank you for your help, really appreciate

Update:

I manage to have it worked via:

```
if(window.innerWidth < 760){
 $('a.mob').on('click', function( e ) {
   e.preventDefault();
   //assumes that by forcing window to go to youtube will kick up option to open in app where experience works - plays my full showreel
   window.location = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0x16ngo8xfY&list=PLzSXIFcDqpiCiKXMtXtVIHnmor9uUsEhC&autoplay=1";
 });
}
```

Any way if the user doesn't have the app install to bring him to the App store link ?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/YouTubeLinks/YouTubeLinks.html

If the app is installed, this will happen automatically

Comment: Hi, thanks I manage to have it worked via this code ( see updated questions), otherwise - is there a way if the user doenst have the youtube app install to bring him to the App store to download it ?

Thanks a lot !